# Android: Fragment finishes an Activity and onActivityResult is not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, activity-finish, onactivityresult

I searched and found tons of `onActivityResult()/startActivityForResult()`  issues, yet I haven't solved my problem.

In my App, I've got a MainActivity which should call a EnterActivity. EnterActivity has two Fragments, a SignupFragment and a LoginFragment. Currently, MainActivity starts EnterActivity with `startActivityForResult()`, it also overrides the `onActivityResult()`.

From SignupFragment / LoginFragment, I call `getActivity().setResult(...)` and `getActivity().finish()`, which finishes EnterActivity, but `MainActivity.onActivityResult()` never gets called.
Can anyone help?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (666 == requestCode) {
            Log.in("gotcha!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnterActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 666);
    }
}
```

The sub-activity looks like this:

```
public class EnterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, new LoginFrament())
            .commit();
    }
}
```

And the Fragment looks like:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
        getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUpLogIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This may just be a typo, but what is `Log.in("gotcha")`?  I don't think `Log` has an `in` method.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's indeed a typo -just wanted a 'place-holder'

Comment: So I played around with what you've supplied here and it worked for me.  I even imported the `v7` support library and tried it with the `ActionBarActivity`.  Is there anything you're leaving out?

Comment: Arg! Yeah, right before the 'startActivityForResultCall()' there is (was) a delayed finish() call, which I suppose was incidentally finishing my MainActivity: `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {@Override
    public void run() {finish();}}, 2500);`